# How to compare two vectors of a same object and get other elements

Tags: c++, vector

I want to compare two object vector element and get the other vector elements of the same object accordingly. For example object has a vector;
   `foo1.a=[4 2 1 3]  foo2.a=[2 1 4]` 
I want to find same elements and then get the other vectors containment correspondingly such as `foo1.b=[8 8 2 10]` and `foo2.b=[8 2 8]` according to findings   I get from `foo.a`. I tried to compare two vectors in the loops and then get the same, but I failed.

Comment: I don't understand. You want to compare two vector elements? Or two vectors? And how do you generate the result vectors?

Comment: holy crap that one paragraph is hard to parse...

Comment: Compare `a` vectors if they have same element get the same index elements from the `b` vector. If they are different, I also want to get that corresponding index element in `b`. As you see, two `a` vector has some same element, I don't want to get the same elements two times.

Comment: I'm going to take a stab at following this: `foo1.a` and `foo2.a` have elements `[2,1,4]` in common, so you want to compare the set `{foo1.b[2], foo1.b[1], foo1.b[4]}`, i.e. `{8,8,10}`, against the set `{foo2.b[2], foo2.b[1], foo2.b[4]}`, i.e. `{8,2,nan}`, and return true if the sets are identical? Is *that* right?? Honestly, sir, this sample needs a **serious** sample that is clear, easy to follow, and demonstrates **all** data values required to show what you're looking for.

Comment: If you notice, we have the same elements in common in both vectors. we should think `foo1.a[1]=4=foo2.a[3]` with `foo1.b[1]=8=foo2.b[1]` together. First, as WhozCraig said, we have to find the elements in common, `2,1,4`, and then get the corresponding element which are same in both b vectors. Lastly, we need to get the different ones ,3, in b. I am sorry for inconvenience and My grammar

Answer (score 4):

Given two vectors:

```
std::vector<int> v1; // {4, 2, 1, 3};
std::vector<int> v2; // {2, 1, 4};
```

First, [`sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) the two vectors so that it's easy to find common elements:

```
std::sort(v1); // {1, 2, 3, 4}
std::sort(v2); // {1, 2, 4}
```

Use [`set_intersection`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/) to find common elements:

```
std::vector<int> vi;
std::set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), vi.begin()); // {1, 2, 4}
```

Use [`set_difference`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/) to find unique elements:

```
std::vector<int> vd;
std::set_difference(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), vd.begin()); // {3}
```

Comment: The question isn't only about finding intersection or difference of the two vectors or sets. And then we should find the corresponding element in b to assign in other vector.